# How can I get all TextEditors,which are open at the top of Editor groups?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an VSCode extension. I want to get all TextEditors for the tab tabs at the top of the Editor groups. How can I do this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733833/1147777

Answer (score -2):

The [`vscode.window.visibleTextEditors`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window) property should have this

```ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

for (const editor of vscode.window.visibleTextEditors) {
    console.log(editor.document.uri)
}
```

Comment: I can only get the current TextEditor by vscode.window.visibleTextEditors.

Comment: `visibleTextEditor` is the set of editors that are at the top of each stack: Left, Center, Right. If you don't see that behavior, please [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)

Comment: This doesn't return tabs that are open, but behind other tabs (which as such aren't visible!)  So frustrating!!!