# Is there a VS Code API function to return all open text editors and their viewcolumn?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I got a [feature request](https://github.com/iulian-radu-at/save-restore-editors/issues/1) for my extension [Save and restore tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iulian-radu-at.save-restore-editors) and to implement it I need to be able to get a list with all opened text editors in all "editor groups".

In the API 1.46 one can get a list of all visible text editors (only one text editor per group) and a list of all open text documents (without any connection to the text editors using them - there can be more text editors for a text document).

Maybe I missed something or someone has a way to get this list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since [VS Code v1.67](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_tab-api) there is the [Tab API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TabGroup) that allows you to inspect all open editor tabs.

This illustrative example would print out the file paths of all open text editors:

```js
for (const tabGroup of vscode.window.tabGroups.all) {
    for (const tab of tabGroup.tabs) {
        if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText) {
            console.info(tab.input.uri);
        }
    }
}
```